# How do I play YouTube videos in an Android app if a user does not have the YouTube app installed?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to play YouTube videos in an Android app. I am using YouTubePlayer API and it works well. But the problem is that I want to have this player in the library and if YouTube app is not installed then the movie is not shown and I also have another problem that on some old phones I need to upgrade the YouTube app first. This is a library that other companies will import I do not want to be dependent on version of YouTube app or if user has the YouTube app. How do I gracefully degrade to play videos within the app?

Comment: did you got solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [YouTubeIntents class](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents) in the Android Player API to gracefully degrade. Here's some sample code to detect what the user can do:

```
if(YouTubeIntents.isYouTubeInstalled(context)) {
   if(YouTubeApiServiceUtil.isYouTubeApiServiceAvailable(context) == YouTubeInitializationResult.SUCCESS) {
   // start the YouTube player
   context.startActivity(
   YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) context, "developer_key", videoId));
 } else if(YouTubeIntents.canResolvePlayVideoIntent(context)) {
   // Start an intent to the YouTube app
   context.startActivity(
   YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntent(context, videoId));
 }
}
// Falls through: last resort - render a webview with an iframe
```

We walk through this code in [our Google I/O talk from 2013](http://youtu.be/Bp3i71jaWNo?t=6m17s), if you're curious. Start from around 6:17.

Comment: Opening video in YouTube app is not an option, because we are making a library that other developer will include. And they will not want to leave their app.

Comment: In that case just remove the "else if" and degrade to a WebView with the iframe player.

Comment: I try this but it does not play video on my old test phone ( Android 2.3.5, Samsung Galaxy S ). It just spin the wheal and after 10 sec the similar videos appears. Should it work on every phone 2.3+?

Comment: There are virtually no guarantees with the iframe player in a webview, unfortunately. However - the percentage of old phones has dropped significantly. The reason you should care about this and test this use case is for Kindle Fire devices, which we believe have a possibility to have significantly more market impact. Kindle Fire devices do not currently support what's needed for in-app playback.

Comment: Yes at the end it looks like we will chose this option. It is not prefect, but it works. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It worked for me! Regarding the fall back option, I am following the conventional approach of showing the video link in browser. 




Intent videoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                                Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
                                                                  + videoId));
startActivity(videoIntent);