# WebView based Android YouTube Player

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I need to add video playback capabilities to an Android app. I've started from integrating this [Android YouTube Player SDK](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/). It works well but the SDK has certain limitation which won't work in my case:

> Users need to run version 4.2.16 of the mobile YouTube app (or higher)
>   to use the API.

[image: no YouTube app is installed]

Same time for iOS there is no native SDK provided by Google but there is a great [alternative WebView based player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) which works just great, without limitations and do exactly what I need. From here I have two questions:

- is it possible to force Native Android YouTube SDK gracefully fallback to WebView based experience if no YouTube app is installed?
- is there a WebView base Android YouTube Player SDK?

**UPDATE:**
I wasn't able to locate existing an implementation (official or 3d party) so just reimplemented whatever is implemented at the [iOS version of the player helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper). Basically this is a WebView which uses an ifame and JS YouTube API to instantiate a player and control it. Unfortunately I wasn't able to start a full screen using that control yet

Comment: Answer to first question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254477/how-do-i-play-youtube-videos-in-an-android-app-if-a-user-does-not-have-the-youtu

Comment: I checked the video and followed the approach, the interesting part is fallback to webview with my custom container, which is works fine using both iframe & iframe api, unfortunately, using this fallback I'm unable to play a fullscreen video. In my case I don't need any controls, just want user to hit my control and start a full screen playback.

Comment: Here is an implementation of a WebView based YouTube player I am working on, it may come in handy :) https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player

Comment: @Alexey Strakh  Did you get solution